# How to draw a node with two options using TikZ graphs in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a node `optionA` with two options `option1` and `option3` which should appear in 45 degrees from the center. Actually, I tried to change this:

```
\tikz \graph [grow right=2cm] { optionA -> option1 -> option2 };
```

to

```
\tikz \graph [grow right=2cm] { optionA -> {option1, option2} };
```

But `option1` and `option2` should equally distanced (45/-45 degrees) from `optionA`.

Thanks for any suggestion.

### Edit:

Here is this within a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [grow right=2cm] { optionA -> {option1, option2} };
\end{document}
```

Comment: @marmot, Binary trees appears in a vertical manner. I wanted just 2 options that will appear horizontally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`binary tree layout` gives you such graphs. The following example requires `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [binary tree layout, level distance=2cm, sibling distance=2cm,
grow=right] { optionA -> {option1, option2} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [binary tree layout, level distance=2cm, sibling distance=2cm] { optionA -> {option1, option2} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For trees you may want to consider using `forest`, which, unlike the above, does not require `lualatex`, and is really powerful.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,edge = {-latex},
s sep=2cm,l sep=2cm
}
[optionA 
 [option1]
 [option2]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first option is exactly how I want to appear them. The `graphdrawing` requires to run LuaLaTex, is it any way that I can avoid to use it :/

Comment: @user4712458 Honestly, if you want to draw such trees you will IMHO be much better off with `forest`, which does not require `lualatex`. AFAIK the graph drawing libraries, on the other hand, do require `lualatex`.

Comment: Yes, using the `forest` now it's perfect! Thank you!!